# How to name files from a text file

Tags: filenames, rename, text-formatting

I have a file `default.txt` and it contains `nameYYYYMM` and I have to name other files e.g. `xyz` to `xyz-nameYYYYMM`
I use `sed` to get date to `default.txt`, but don't I know how to make it string(?) so i can use it to name other files.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your shell. In bash you may say `"$(<default.txt)"` to capture the contents of the file `default.txt` into a string. Both dash and bash accept `"$(cat default.txt)"`. For example, if `default.txt` contains `test201611`, then

```
mv xyz xyz-"$(cat default.txt)"
```

will rename the file `xyz` to `xyz-test201611`.

Comment: Thx its working. Now i want to grep all files (xyz_aa_2016) and change its names. iam doing something like this, but its not working and i have 0 clue:
`find /path -type f -print | grep /'_aa_'/ | mv *_aa_2* xyz_aa$(cat default.txt)"`

Comment: newname="$(cat default.txt)" ; find /path -type f -name "xyz_aa_*" -exec mv "{}" "xyz_aa_$newname" \;

Comment: Thx @AlexP, but it took my 3 files and converted to 1, what is the command to do each for each file. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You have to use different names for each file... For example, by numbering them. Or, if the files are in different directories, keep the new file in the same directory as the old file -- `newname="$(cat default.txt)" find /path -type f -name "xyz_aa_2016" -exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(dirname "{}")/xyz_aa_$newname"' \;` Never run a command unless you are sure that you understand what it does.

Comment: I'm learning and working on my test files. it's fine :) thank you for help, cheers